# Seeing user files as domain administrator

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

Is it possible to allow a domain administrator to view user files on individual machines?

I don't need to do a remote desktop login, and only need read-only access. Is it possible to do this without resetting the user's password when the admin needs to view their files?

Using Windows Server 2008 R2

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a Domain Admin, then that gives you local administrator privileges on the domain-joined member servers and workstations.

You can use this to give yourself permission to view the files, but you may have to update the ACLs on the files first. You may even need to take ownership of the files, if "Administrators" is not in the ACL to begin with.

It can be done, but you will have to "give yourself permission to do it" first.